# How to Filter store in extjs?

Tags: extjs

How to do store filter in extjs?

```
 fieldLabel    : 'Status',
 xtype         : 'combo',
 name          : 'status',
 store    : new Ext.data.ArrayStore({ fields : ['status'], data : [['A'],['B'],['C']),
 displayField  : 'status',
 valueField   : 'status',
 autoSelect       : true,
 typeAhead     : true,
 validateOnBlur: true,
 queryMode    : 'local'
```

I need to do filter based on some condition.. Sample

```
if(Somecondition)
.... filter A and B
elseif(Somecondition)
   filter B
else
  Filter only A and C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is a solution that will change the values of the combo box to a specific subset of the three options. If "Somecondition" is supposed to filter an arbitrary set of data, then I am going to need to know more about how "Somecondition" relates to the data.

```
{
            fieldLabel: 'Status',
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'status',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['status'],
                data: [{
                    'status': 'A'
                }, {
                    'status': 'B'
                }, {
                    'status': 'C'
                }, ]
            }),
            displayField: 'status',
            valueField: 'status',
            autoSelect: true,
            typeAhead: true,
            validateOnBlur: true,
            queryMode: 'local',
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function(t) {
                    if (Somecondition) {
                        t.store.loadData([{
                            'status': 'A'
                        }, {
                            'status': 'B'
                        }])
                    } else if (Somecondition) {
                        t.store.loadData([{
                            'status': 'B'
                        }])
                    } else {
                        t.store.loadData([{
                            'status': 'A'
                        }, {
                            'status': 'C'
                        }])
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This only i need.. thanks for helping.. its work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
statusStore.clearFliter();
statusStore.filter(function(r) {
            var value = r.get('status');
            return (value == "A" || value == "B");
    });
```

Using store filter also i get the result.

ClearFliter is to remove previous value in that store.